# DECIMAL POINTS and Multiplication with decimals

Tags: bash, shell, decimal, multiplication

So, when a user inputs a 4 digit number like 4750 the program MUST convert that two decimal places over converting that number to be $47.50. This will be stored in cost_in_cents. This is the code that i have so far that its just calculations. The messages are already being printed at a different function I just need help coding calculations with decimal numbers.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
 Percent=20
 Numguests=DO_NOT_CHANGE     # number of elements in ${GUESTS}
 Limit=DO_NOT_CHANGE          # $num_guests * $BUDGET_PER_PERSON
 Cost=DO_NOT_CHANGE           # prompt user
 Tip=DO_NOT_CHANGE            # $cost * $percent%
 Totalcost=DO_NOT_CHANGE      # $cost + $tip
 Averagecost=DO_NOT_CHANGE   # $overall_cost / $num_guests

function calc {
echo -n "What is the total cost in cents (not including tip)? ";
read cost_in_cents 
Numguests=8
Limit=$((8 * 25))
Cost=$cost_in_cents  #needs to convert into decimal
Tip=$(($Cost * $Percent)) #needs to be in decimal
Overall_cost=$(($Cost + $Tip)) #needs to have decimal
Average_cost=$(($Totalcost /8)) #needs to be in decimal
}
```

How can i covert cost_in_cents by two decimal places (so if the number is 4315 its converted into $43.15 or if the number is 50 its actually $0.50) and multiply it together WITHOUT it rounding up

Comment: divide by 100...

Comment: when i divide by 100 it gives me this 
/: is a directory
    Cost=$cost_in_cents/100

Comment: it's already being printed out at a different function and i cannot change it. since echo "/ your code" will print it out correct?

Comment: wait hold on let me check

Comment: No the echo sends the output to `bc` which does the math, you can also do `Cost=$(( cost_in_cents / 100 ))`...

Comment: for the 
 
Cost=$(( cost_in_cents / 100 ))
it gives me an output of 0 not .02

Comment: $cost_in_cents/100 - you forgot the $

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou: variables don't need leading `$` when put inside `$(( ... ))`

Comment: i divide it by 100 but it gives me 0 as the output. 
when i put 2/100 it gives me 0 not .02

Comment: @Bob, bash isn't the best for doing floating point math, it tends to round things in undesirable ways; there are other tools you might want to consider... like `awk`.

Comment: "bash isn't the best for doing floating point math" is a considerable understatement: bash *does not* do floating point arithmetic, integer only. ksh can do floating point, or of course bc which is a calculator, or awk/perl/python/... which are general purpose programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this and many other computations directly in `awk`.  Here is one example...

```
value=4315; cost=$(awk "BEGIN{print $value/100}"); echo $cost

43.15
```

if you want to control the decimal numbers change to `printf \"%.2f\n\", $value/100`

Comment: 14 seconds difference! Incredible!

Comment: alternatives are good.

Comment: is there a way to ensure its always two decimal places? when i try to input 2000 it prints out 20 and not 20.00, or when multiplying with the percentage it does 23.4 instead of 23.40. like to keep it at constant two decimal places, it at times even gives me up to 5 decimal places.

Comment: please see the rest of my answer, replace print statement with the alternative

Comment: okay thanks ill try it out!

Comment: wait so do i ignore the awk and just add the printf

Comment: Replace print statement with the printf statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can do maths in bc but even in awk:

```
$ cost="3444"
$ cost2=$(awk '{print $0/100}' <<<"$cost")
$ echo "$cost ==> $cost2"
3444 ==> 34.44
```